# How to cite a multi-part title with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I'm using JabRef to construct a bibliography database and I would like to add one of the [Hazus technical manuals](https://www.fema.gov/media-library-data/20130726-1820-25045-6286/hzmh2_1_eq_tm.pdf) into the database. However the title of the manual I'm interested has multiple lines, each in a different font:

> Multi-hazard Loss Estimation Methodology
>
> Earthquake Model
>
> Hazus-MH 2.1
>
> Technical Manual

I'm not sure how this ought to be included in an entry like this:

```
@Manual{FEMAMD,
  title        = {What to put here?},
  author       = {{Federal Emergy Management Agency Mitigation Division}},
  organization = {{Department of Homeland Security}},
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on your style. But I think I'd do:

```
  @Manual{FEMAMD,
    title        = {Multi-hazard Loss Estimation Methodology: Eathquake Model (Technical Manual)},
    edition      = {Hazus-MH~2.1},
    author       = {{Federal Energy Management Agency Mitigation Division}},
    organization = {{Department of Homeland Security}},
  }
```

Which seems to preserve the semantics pretty well. As far as I can see the numbers are effectively version numbers, so they belong in "edition". You should have a date as well, probably. It seems (see comments) that "Technical Manual" needs to go  in there somewhere to avoid ambiguity. If you were using `biblatex` I would put everything after "Methodology" in a subtitle field.

Comment: The case you make is quite convincing, except that I am using JabRef which doesn't seem to allow the "subtitle field" for  a Manual. Do you have any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Also nowhere in the entry is the "Technical Manual" part of the title included...

Comment: Ah. If you are using bibtex, not biblatex (sorry to be slow), I'd just stick the Subtitle as part of the title! The technical manual I would not regard as part of the title: it's a description (like "book"). It's quite useless information for the reader. Is there *some other* work with the same title which differs only in *not* being a technical manual? But if you disagree, or if there is some other work, stick that in the title as well!

Comment: Well yes. There is the user manual: https://www.fema.gov/media-library-data/20130726-1820-25045-1179/hzmhs2_1_eq_um.pdf

Comment: I just modified the link in my original question to link to the actual PDF of the Technical manual

Comment: If they are two separate works, then I'd put it in the title or subtitle.

Comment: You could also use further LaTeX commands in the BibTeX or BibLaTeX database.  E.g. `title={Multi-hazard Loss Estimation Methodology: \texttt{Eathquake Model}},` which should print the second part in a typewriter font.  But I agree with @paulstanley that the database should store an abstract form and not necessarily copy the title typography elements verbatim.  The bibliography should enable the user to order this book from his library, not to facsimile the look of the Manual itself.

Comment: The proposed title doesn't mention Hazus which is the name of the software this technical manual is all about.

Comment: Just for your information, JabRef also supports biblatex. In the end you could also add a custom field and adapt the style to format in a proper way