# Technical reports in BibTex/JabRef

Tags: bibtex, citing, jabref

I have a couple of issues with adding technical reports in JabRef/BibTeX

**FIRST ISSUE**

Multi part titles: Some technical reports have complex, multi-part titles. The various parts tell you quite a bit about the context of the report. For example the title of [this report](https://ramses-cities.eu/fileadmin/uploads/Deliverables_Uploaded/Development_of_a_library_of_impact_functions_and_general_uncertainty_measures_D1.2.pdf) contains several parts:

> RAMSES PROJECT
>
> WP1.2: Development of a library of impact functions
>
> D1.2: Development of a library of impact functions and general uncertainty measures

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519460/how-to-cite-a-multi-part-title-with-bibtex/519464?noredirect=1#comment1313722_519464) has partially addressed the problem of multipart titles. However many titles contain more than just two parts. [Here's an example of a document with a multi-part title.](https://www.fema.gov/media-library-data/20130726-1820-25045-1179/hzmhs2_1_eq_um.pdf)

**SECOND ISSUE**

The second issue is regarding the `institution` key in BibTeX. Many technical reports are developed by one institution for the benefit of another institution (the client). [This paper](http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/605381501489019613/pdf/117790-WP-PUBLIC-Alexandria-PHASE-2-ENGLISH.pdf) is a great example where the report was generated by the entities "AASTMT" and "Egis BCEOM International" on behalf of the World Bank. In this case, which institution should be included in the `institution` field for the dedicated entry in JabRef/BibTeX? Do the other institutions get completely ignored or is there a dedicated field for them?

How can I make correct use of JabRef and/or BibTeX to take all this into consideration? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ultimately it is your bibliography style that decides what gets shown in the output. Especially with more specialised issues like this there may well be differences between styles, so you may have to play around with the available fields a bit to get what you want in the output.

Comment: I'd like to think of `institution` as a replacement/near-equivalent for `publisher`. I'd also recommend not to shy away from putting organisations or corporations into the `author` or `editor` field (just remember the braces: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864). So in the example I might put `AASTMT` and `{Egis BCEOM International}` into the `author` field and `World Bank` into `institution`.

Comment: @moewe I'd like to fill in as many required/optional fields as I can and let the system decide how to display the bibliography. Is there like an official "BibTeX guide" on how to do these particular types of reports?

Comment: What I was trying to point out is that depending on your bibliography style there may be different optional and required field. (Take the example of URLs. The base styles `plain.bst` and friends don't know a field `url`, so if you want to give a URL there, the standard workaround is to put it into the `howpublished` field. Many newer styles - notably the `natbib` styles - have a dedicated `url` field, which should ideally be used there (because it gives the style more control over the output). So what do you do? Do you use `howpublished` or `url`?)

Comment: The closest you will get to an official BibTeX guide is the collection of documents found at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtex (you'll be especially interested in section 3 of [`btxdoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf)). There is a 'core' set of BibTeX types and fields that is pretty much the same for most styles (by convention), but that core is old (late eighties, I believe, so doesn't mention URLs for example) and doesn't cover everything.

Comment: I personally would recommend switching to biblatex and biber. They offer a various set of standard fields and include urls etc https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex JabRef also supports biblatex